# Empty lines,text are generated when loading view in CodeIgniter

Tags: view, continuous-integration, space, lines

well, my view consists of 3 parts header, content and footer
when I load the view using

```
    $this->load->view("admin/header")
    $this->load->view("admin/content");
    $this->load->view("admin/footer");
```

it generates some empty lines as follows :

[image: empty space]

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me when loading UTF8 encoded files. I haven't found a way to get reliably get rid of it but I often work around it by either saving the sub-files as ASCII or UTF8 without a Byte-order-mark.

Hope this helps.